# Regex to grab second parameter group

Tags: c#, regex

My current regex is as follows:

```
(?<token>#gallery (?<id>[^#]+)#)
```

I use this to grab some information.

In the case of `#gallery d23d23d#`

It would greab `d23d23d` as the groupd named `Id`.

I need to extend this to allow for additional parameters so I could grab

`#gallery d23d23d foo#` and get `d23d23d` and `foo` as seperate groups?

My regex skills are hopeless some help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture exactly two groups use:

```
(?<token>#gallery\s+(?<id>[^\s#]+)\s+(?<foo>[^\s#]+)#)
```

The group `foo` will contain the second capture group. Note the use of `\s` to account for whitespace characters other than a space and the use of `\s+` between the groups to allow for more than one whitespace character between parameters.

To capture zero, one, *or* two groups use:

```
(?<token>#gallery(?:\s+(?<p1>[^\s#]+)(?:\s+(?<p2>[^\s#]+)(?:\s+(?<p3>[^\s#]+))?)?)?#)
```

The groups `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` will contain the first the groups when they appear they are not required for `token` to match.

To capture any number of groups (including none) use

```
(?<token>#gallery(?:\s+(?<id>[^\s#]+))*#)
```

Although the `Value` of group `id` will contain only the last matched parameter, it's `Captures` property will contain all the other parameters.

Comment: testing on http://gskinner.com/RegExr first one no longer just captures one group, and second one just grabs all additional as a single group...

Comment: mmm almost there, is there no way to use the third option `(?<token>#gallery(?: (?<id>[^ #]+))*#)` but have each value between the whitespace to be in a seperate group?

Comment: @shenku You can't put them in a separate group without explicitly creating separate groups for them, but then you're limited to the number of groups you specify. I supposed you could just define an arbitrarily large number of groups following my second pattern as a guide: `(?<token>#gallery (?<p1>[^ #]+)(?: (?<p2>[^ #]+)(?: (?<p3>[^ #]+)(?: (?<p4>[^ #]+))?)?)?#)` will match 1 to 4 parameters, but as you can see, this gets out of hand pretty quickly.

Comment: okay I see, I see - can you change `(?<token>#gallery (?<id>[^ #]+)(?: (?<foo>[^ #]+))?#)` to include zero, one or two groups and that should be perfect for me (right now) - thanks for your input.

Comment: @shenku I've included it in my answer for completeness.